# Calculating difference between adjacent cosine values in list

Tags: python

I'd like to find out the difference cosine function values ​​for the values ​​1 to 10 .
So:

```
import math
import sys
import string
import os

for n in range (1,11): 
        x = math.cos (n)
        print x
```

This simple script  print the value of cosine for n = 1 to 10 Now I need determine differences between individual values ​​and take it from the value for n = 2 and readings from the value for n = 1 Then take the value for n = 3 and n =2
So:

```
Math.cos (2) - Math.cos (1)

Math.cos (3) - Math.cos (2)

Math.cos (4) - Math.cos (3)

.

.

Math.cos (10) - Math.cos (9)
```

and finally

```
Math.cos (10) - Math.cos (1)
```

then I would like to add up the values ​​... but I'd already put together perhaps

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, [that's irrelevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag).

Comment: @TylerCrompton I read that,I think that if it's homework people try to help the user figure the logic out instead of just answering the question, eventually the question gets answered regardless but the OP gets to learn more, I think both sides benefit from the exchange.

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're asking, but assuming I understand you correctly, the final result will always be `2 * Math.cos(1)` such that `n > 1`.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like:

```
for x,y in zip(range(2,11)+[10],range(1,10)+[1]):
    print math.cos(x) - math.cos(y)
```

Of course, this only works on python2.x where `range` returns a list.  To get around that, you could use `itertools.chain`.  i.e.:  `range(2,11)+[10]` becomes `chain(range(2,11),[10])`.  The key function to learn here is [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 1):

Untested:

```
import math

cosines = map(math.cos, xrange(1, 11))
cosines.append(cosines[0])

from operator import sub
print map(sub, cosines[1:], cosines[:-1])
```

Comment: I think this gets the sign wrong on the final element (although, OP's requirement is a little flaky anyway).  +1 for avoiding a bunch of re-calcs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple `for` loops together, like this:

```
for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in range(1, 11):
        print("x is %s, y is %s" % (x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import cos

cosines = [cos(i) for i in range(1,11)]

print [b-a for a,b in zip(cosines, cosines[1:]+cosines[0])]
```